# Erro de Exceção "' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1"

Tags: c#, xml, windows, exceção, windows-phone-8-1

Tenho um aplicativo feito em `C#` para mostrar o cardápio do restaurante universitário da minha universidade, o qual pega as informações por meio de um `XML`. O aplicativo permite a consulta individual de cada refeição (café da manhã, almoço e jantar). Ocorre que em momentos aleatórios do dia, quando alguma das consultas é solicitada, ocorre um erro e o aplicativo fecha bruscamente. Verificando com um `debug`, percebi que aparece a seguinte mensagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Erro**

> " ' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1,
>   position 1".

Estou usando agora um bloco `try/catch` para ver se consigo evitar o fechamento brusco, mas não consegui ainda.

- Alguém poderia me ajudar a dar o devido tratamento a este erro?
- Como posso resolver esse problema, pelo menos para evitar o fechamento brusco da aplicação?

O meu bloco try/catch por enquanto fiz apenas isso, para tentar evitar que ele feche. O método LoadDataHoje() está como um loop, para que ele fique executando e tente conseguir acessar a informação.

```
catch (System.ArgumentException erro)  
            {  
                LoadDataHoje();  
                contador++;  
                if(contador == 5)  
                {  
                    throw new ArgumentException();  
                    MessageBox.Show("O servidor está retornando um erro, tente novamente daqui a pouco :/","Erro no servidor", MessageBoxButton.OK);  
                    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Src/Pages/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));  
                }  
            }
```

Verifiquei agora pelo debug que quando ele cai nessa exceção, ao final ele mostra outro erro, como na imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Obrigado.

Comment: Coloque o erro e o código onde o erro está sendo apontado.

Comment: Olá você poderia incluir o trecho de código inserido no  `try catch` ? , os detalhes sobre o seu código irão nos ajudar a resolver o seu problema , basta editar a pergunta.

Comment: Possivelmente um problema de enconding? Acredito que você tenha q formatar seu resultado em ASCII. Ou modificar as configurações.do seu parser pra ler utf-8.

Comment: Eu queria pelo menos evitar que o aplicativo fechasse bruscamente, mas mesmo com esse catch ele tá fechando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar o fechamento brusco altere o seu código assim:

```
try
{
     ...
}
catch (System.ArgumentException erro)
{
    LoadDataHoje();
    contador++;
    if (contador == 5)
    {
        // throw new ArgumentException(); Remova isso!!!-> Esse cara está fechando a aplicação.
        MessageBox.Show("O servidor está retornando um erro, tente novamente daqui a pouco :/", "Erro no servidor", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Src/Pages/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)//Por precausão
{
     ...
}
```

Quanto a função `XDocument.Parse(e.Result)`, o erro pode ser causado por causa da codificação do texto.